# How do I upload my own library to Nexus one?

Tags: android, android-ndk, nexus-one

I'm porting my native C engine to `android 2.1 using NDK r6`, but I can't use the commands like: `adb root` or `adb remout` to my Nexus one. How should I do to upload my engine (.so file) to Nexus one?

Comment: You use the NDK to add your C engine to an Android application so your C engine would be part of a APK and you upload it onto the phone with that, If you want to add your C engine to Android itself you need to create your own ROM from scratch and put it on your device

Comment: Also, there is no NDKr6 publicly available. There is an NDKr3 available for download, though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't add extra libraries on the phone (and rely on them). Your application should supply whatever extra libraries it needs packed within the apk and use them (and only them).